# Xamarin Form Debug Errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't even know where to start debugging on this one so please let me know what else i can do to find out more information.

When I load my Xamarin Forms application in the output from Debug I see lines like this

`A first chance exception of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException' occurred in Xamarin.F`orms.Xaml.DLL

Then further down I see a huge amount errors repeated such as

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

And that just keeps repeating. However my application works perfectly fine, no issues at all in the running of the application but it feels a little sluggish and I suspect it is due to these.

Can anyone tell me how to find out more information on what is causing these?

**Update 1**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Is caused by

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Am I meant to use Auto instead?

[image]

**Update 2**

Ok, I discovered Ctl - Alt - E. and adding the exception types in.

First issue is

```
 <RelativeLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="ContentContainer" BackgroundColor="Black" Opacity="0.7" Orientation="Vertical"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=0}"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                        Property=Height,
                                        Factor=0.33}"
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                        Property=Width,
                                        Factor=1.00}"
                         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                        Property=Height,
                                        Factor=0.33}">
                                </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The error is

```
Additional information: Type ConstraintExpressionExtension not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms
```

But the Xaml works fine, it just throws the error.

Comment: I believe this will be due to your XAML markup.  There is most likely a call which your doing in a converter that isn't precise enough in the call that your executing, hence the ambiguity, or perhaps some wrong datatypes being used that you didn't really intend.  If you can isolate and post I can take a look for you?  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: Found one cause of one of the errors

Comment: It should be ok.  Can you just check that your using the latest version of everything?  Go into file explorer for each platform specific project to verify all libraries are v1.2.3x

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Core and Xamarin.Forms.Xaml are both 1.2.3.0. The Nuget package is 1.2.3.6257

Comment: Create a new project, and add this code into a simple page and run to verify if this is the real reason for failure?

Comment: Brand new project with the latest everything and same appears with just a Grid and those row and column definitions

Comment: Could you send across and I will take a look?

Comment: What platform are you trying this on also?

Comment: I have sent the project. Trying this on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I haven't solved all of them but here is one I will share, thanks to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26220/help-please-setbinding-imagecell-imagesourceproperty-iconsource-string-crash-on-wp

Basically any images cause errors because the image source is not automatically converted to an ImageSource in WP. Where as it is on Android and iOS.

So you need to use a converter.

```
cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, 
    new Binding("IconSource", BindingMode.OneWay, new StringToImageConverter())); 

public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter  { 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
        var filename = (string)value; 
        return ImageSource.FromFile(filename); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } }
```

I will see if I can find the remaining source of the issues and post them here.

**Update:** the other was a bug in the XF framework that was fixed when XamlC came out.

Answer (score 0):

The sample solution did work for me, however it did re-download some references.

I did notice that you had it in Release configuration, of which in the solution that you sent there was no files.

It sounds like something has gone a-miss somewhere.  Can you try the following:-

1) Try cleaning the solution and rebuilding and test.

2) Change from Release, to Debug, then Clean and test, and then back to Release and Clean and test.

3) Delete the obj and bin directories from the file system in the platform-specific projects, and do a rebuild.

Hopefully one of the above should resolve the small solution example issue your experiencing?

Comment: I cleaned the solution to reduce the file size when emailing. The solution runs, that's not the problem, its just the Debug Output messages that are concerning me and what is doing it.

Comment: I added a picture to the original question just to make sure we are on the same page. If I remove the Grid Row and Column Definitions but still keep the Grid, I never see those 2 outputs.

Comment: Yes - I understand, but when I check my Output dialog box I get the exit codes etc, however none of the 'ArgumentException' lines that you are for the small sample solution you sent.

Comment: I had another quick look at this today, but still not able to re-produce from your sample.  If it doesn't crash your application, then maybe there is a verbose on debugging that I am not aware off - i was only able to see options for build output in VS that really don't fit this scenario.  I could take a quick look on TeamViewer, but I think because this is not crashing your App at all, then it maybe some sort of elevated debug log perhaps, so there are doing a `try` `catch` however the catch is an empty block perhaps?  It maybe best to contact Xamarin perhaps for more clarification on this?

Comment: HI Pete, just finding out the actual errors. I have updated the main question with the first error and an actual error message. The code looks fine, its the same as example but it looks like the error is within the xaml schema file which I have no idea on what it looks like or how to fix one of these errors.